Result of FTIR and RAMAN calculations for SiPOCa structure
Using Quantum Espresso models this structure with the following input files. However, the ph.x IR column always shows zero. Does anyone know why this result?
ph.x input:
&inputph
  tr2_ph=1.0d-14,
  prefix='Si2CaP3O14',
  amass(1)=28.08550,
  amass(2)=40.07800,
  amass(3)=30.97376,
  amass(4)=15.99940,
  outdir='./tmp'
  epsil=.false.,
  ! lraman=.true.
  trans=.true.,
  asr=.true.
  fildyn='Si2CaP3O14.dyn'
 /
 0.0 0.0 0.0

dynmat.x input:
&input 
fildyn='Si2CaP3O14',
fileig='Si2CaP3O14.dat', 
filmol='SiCaPO.mold',
/

Inspecting the output file:
$ awk 'NR==1,/mode/{next}/DYNMAT/,NR==0{next}{print}' arquivo-dyn.out > arquivo-dyn.dat
    1   -405.80  -12.1657    0.0000
    2   -405.80  -12.1657    0.0000
    3   -389.04  -11.6630    0.0000
    4   -389.04  -11.6630    0.0000
    5   -136.64   -4.0962    0.0000
    6   -136.64   -4.0962    0.0000
    7   -101.05   -3.0295    0.0000
    8   -100.17   -3.0030    0.0000
    9   -100.17   -3.0030    0.0000
   10    -27.37   -0.8204    0.0000
   11     13.92    0.4173    0.0000
   12     13.92    0.4173    0.0000
   13    139.92    4.1946    0.0000
   14    139.92    4.1946    0.0000
   15    184.62    5.5349    0.0000
   16    184.62    5.5349    0.0000
   17    234.80    7.0390    0.0000
   18    244.60    7.3329    0.0000
   19    244.60    7.3329    0.0000
   20    273.87    8.2103    0.0000
   21    299.83    8.9886    0.0000
   22    299.83    8.9886    0.0000
   23    314.49    9.4282    0.0000
   24    340.48   10.2072    0.0000
   25    365.65   10.9619    0.0000
   26    389.67   11.6819    0.0000
   27    389.67   11.6819    0.0000
   28    404.08   12.1139    0.0000
   29    440.13   13.1947    0.0000
   30    440.13   13.1947    0.0000
   31    457.46   13.7143    0.0000
   32    457.46   13.7143    0.0000
   33    462.65   13.8698    0.0000
   34    495.20   14.8458    0.0000
   35    495.20   14.8458    0.0000
   36    502.81   15.0738    0.0000
   37    584.34   17.5180    0.0000
   38    584.34   17.5180    0.0000
   39    593.26   17.7856    0.0000
   40    593.26   17.7856    0.0000
   41    617.65   18.5168    0.0000
   42    662.03   19.8473    0.0000
   43    680.84   20.4110    0.0000
   44    714.18   21.4104    0.0000
   45    714.18   21.4104    0.0000
   46    801.14   24.0177    0.0000
   47    801.14   24.0177    0.0000
   48    810.68   24.3034    0.0000
   49    936.45   28.0741    0.0000
   50   1056.42   31.6706    0.0000
   51   1056.42   31.6706    0.0000
   52   1074.53   32.2135    0.0000
   53   1074.53   32.2135    0.0000
   54   1096.94   32.8853    0.0000
   55   1149.65   34.4657    0.0000
   56   1150.49   34.4907    0.0000
   57   1150.49   34.4907    0.0000
   58   1216.01   36.4551    0.0000
   59   1832.39   54.9338    0.0000
   60   1936.77   58.0628    0.0000


Don't you need the dielectric constant to calculate IR intensities? You have set epsil=.false., which means the dielectric constant won't be calculated, so neither will the IR intensities.

Before I had set episol=.true. following suggestions from another user who answered my question

Entrada:
&inputph
tr2_ph=1.0d-14,
prefix='Si2CaP3O14',
amass(1)=28.08550,
amass(2)=40.07800,
amass(3)=30.97376,
amass(4)=15.99940,
outdir='./tmp'
epsil=.true.,
! lraman=.true.
trans=.true.,
asr=.true.
fildyn='Si2CaP3O14.dyn'
/
0.0 0.0 0.0
Saída:
Error in routine phq_readin (1):
no elec. field with metals

I remember that question. It doesn't really make a lot of sense anyway to calculate dielectric constant / IR/ Raman etc. for a metal anyway, so I don't see the problem... is your compound a metal?

It's a Bioglass "P3Ca(SiO7)2"

That doesn't answer the question. Is your material a metal or not? If it's a metal, you cant do epsil=.true. calcs. If it's not a metal, try running again using occupations that aren't metallic.
